# Pass an entire inital object in an edit form (data pre-population) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a very complicated form and I choose to not use `ModelForm` since I needed flexibility and control over the fields. Since I am not using `ModelForm`, I can't simply do something like `instance=order`, where `order = Order.objects.get(pk=1)`.

Currently I am pre-populating every field with `initial` in the `forms.py` as oppose to the `views.py` like this

```
self.fields['work_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Order.WORK_TYPE_CHOICES, initial=order.work_type)
```

But I was wondering if I could pass the entire `order` object to a form or do I have to declare `initial` to *every* field?

Is there a way to do something like

```
order_form = OrderEditForm(data=request.POST, initial=order)
```

in `views.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference to other people:

I have since found out after reading SO's comments and answers that it's better to use `ModelForm` even if you end up explicitly defining every field manually (using something like `self.fields['foo'] = forms.CharField()`).

In any case, if you are trying to pass a dictionary of current values in a form then the best (built-in) way to convert a model to a dictionary is actually using `model_to_dict`:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

order = Order.objects.get(pk=1)
dictionary = model_to_dict(order)
form = OrderEditForm(dictionary)
```

I got the solution from [this blog](http://www.ironzebra.com/news/3/how-to-quickly-create-a-django-edit-form-from-object-instance). I hope this will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a very complicated form and I choose to not use ModelForm since
>   I needed flexibility and control over the fields

Everything that you can do using a Form, you can do in a ModelForm such as adding new fields or over-riding attributes on the fields etc.

> But I was wondering if I could pass the entire order object to a form
>   or do I have to declare initial to every field?

You can pass the order object into the form but you will still have to populate each field individually either in the forms or in the view function.

So in your view you would do something like this:

```
intial = {'order_number': order.number, 'order_id': order.id}

form = OrderForm(initial=initial)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prepopulate data to a form is passing a dictionary as first argument to de form constructor.

```
order_form = OrderEditForm(order.__dict__())
```

where `__dict__()` is a method that passes "order" object attributes to a dictionary with each attribute's name as a key and their content as value.

An example of how to "invent" such a method could be something like:

```
order_initial = Order.objects.filter(pk=order.pk).values()[0]
```

and then construct the form with:

```
order_form = OrderEditForm(order_initial)
```

Look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) example (how they populate values at "post" time):

Comment: Why is it that you can't do `values()` from a `get(pk=order.pk)`?

Comment: Because get doesn't return a queryset. It returns an object. So if you do that you will get an Exception because your object (probably) doesn't understand "values" message.